# how to get paper.path NUMBER with raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using this code:

```
var current = null;
for ( var state in aus) {
    aus[state].color = Raphael.getColor();
    (function(st, state) {
        st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
        st[0].onmouseover = function() {
            current && aus[current].animate({
                fill : "#333",
                stroke : "#666"
            }, 500) && (document.getElementById(current).style.display = "");
            st.animate({
                fill : st.color,
                stroke : "#ccc"
            }, 500);
            st.toFront();
            R.safari();
            document.getElementById(state).style.display = "block";
            current = state;
        };
        st[0].onmouseout = function() {
            st.animate({
                fill : "#333",
                stroke : "#666"
            }, 500);
            st.toFront();
            R.safari();
        };
        if (state == "nsw") {
            st[0].onmouseover();
        }
    })(aus[state], state);
}
```

from this page: http://raphaeljs.com/australia.htm

and I have added this:

```
st[0].onmousedown = function() {
    paper.print();
    var url = "index.php?cmd=2&sub=0";
    window.open(url, "popup");
};
```

into the for loop to open a popup window generated by a php script.

The 'sub' request-parameter would be a numerical value corresponding with folders associated with states, but I don't know how to associate numbers with it.

Let's say that each state would be a number from 0 to the number of states.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create id's for each state:

```
var ids = {}, i = 0;
for (var state in aus) {
  ids[state] = i;
  i++;
}
```

and then:

```
var url = "index.php?cmd=2&sub=" + ids[state];
```

Comment: Simple and nice! it's just about making a numerical array, I didn't think about it, thank you.